# Is it possible and okay to redirect to an .html from a .xhtml and viceversa?

Tags: java, html, xhtml

For example if my user is on a view.xhtml and then he clicks a button that takes him to a view.html and viceversa, is that possible and fine?

I would try it right now but not possible at the moment, just ideas that come and id like to validate through you guys :)

Comment: What's Java got to do with this question? Is this in relation to a particular Java framework?

Comment: The question in the title is not the same as in the body, but the answer to both is yes. Do you have any indication that it is not?

Comment: @Alohci, yeah im using Spring framework mate, and okay thanks Mr Lister